# Asyncio on CircuitPython doesn't runs two functions concurrently

Tags: python-asyncio, raspberry-pi-pico, adafruit-circuitpython

I am actually on a project that needs concurentials functions... but I don't really know (and understand) a lot about it.
My program must run on a Raspberry pi pico with Circuitpython. I did some research and the most suitable library for this is Asyncio.

Here is in a nutshell my program:

```
async def playAudio(import 1, import 2):
   *some actions....*
   print("audio") #added this to debug
   if audio not played yet:
      playAudio()

async def lcdScreen(import 1, import 2):
    
    print("LCD") #added this to debug
    *some actions....*
    lcd.print("*something*")
    time.sleep(1)
    lcd.print("*something else*")
    time.sleep(1)

async def story(imports of both functions)
    L = await asyncio.gather(
       playAudio(imports),
       playAudio(imports),
      )
    print(l)

while True:
   *some actions....*

   asyncio.run(story(*all imports)
```

When I run the program, I get:

```
Audio
*then a while later:*
LCD
```

This might be a beginner problem, but I can't figure out how to make this work. I checked online and saw that I need ```await``, but again can't figure out how to apply it to this case :(

I imported Asyncio with Circup from a Windows 11

Thanks for your help !

NOTE: I tried to follow examples from [Asyncio Library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#running-tasks-concurrently)

Comment: Remember that asyncio only runs things *concurrently*, but not *in parallel*. If your code never yields control back to the scheduler (by calling `await` on something), then other async coroutines will never have the chance to run. Because `playAudio` never calls `await`, nothing else can run until the function completes.

Comment: Thank's @larsks for your comment. Isn't there any way yo make them work in parallel ? Or do I have to buy another pico to run the audio script ?

Comment: I don't think there's enough of your code here to answer that question. It's not clear how `playAudio` is implemented, and in the sample you've posted nothing actually calls `lcdScreen`.

Comment: Thanks again for your anwser. I actually followed your advice and tried to find another way to run my program without parallel  running functions. You are right, my sample is quite lite, but I tried to give in the simpliest way my program just to show what I wanted.